# Why can I not match a URI in a sparql query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, raptor2, rasqal

I'm writing a sparql query to search in the following `rdfxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:bqbiol="http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="PhysicalEntity0001">
    <bqbiol:is rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/uniprot/PD12345"/>
    <bqbiol:isPartOf rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/fma/fma:1234"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="SemsimMetaid0000">
    <bqbiol:isPropertyOf rdf:resource="PhysicalEntity0001"/>
    <bqbiol:isVersionOf rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/opb/opb_1234"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This query:

```
                "SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?resource\n"
                "WHERE { \n"
                "   ?subject ?predicate ?resource .\n"
                "}";
```

Works as I expect and produces:

```
subject,predicate,resource
SemsimMetaid0000,http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/isPropertyOf,PhysicalEntity0000
PhysicalEntity0000,http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/is,https://identifiers.org/uniprot/PD12345
PhysicalEntity0000,http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/isPartOf,https://identifiers.org/fma/fma:1234
```

when formatted as `csv`. However this:

```
                "SELECT ?predicate ?resource\n"
                "WHERE { \n"
                "   <SemsimMetaid0000> ?predicate ?resource .\n"
                "}";
```

comes up as an empty result set. Can anybody tell me why ?

Notes:

- I'm using a `C` library called `rasqal` to execute the query and the rdf graph is `raptor` (if that means anything to any of you =])
- All nodes are URI / IRI nodes so trying `"SemsimMetaid0000"` does not work either.
- There is no base uri at the point of searching the rdf graph. A base uri is required for serializing to `rdfxml` but at the point of searching the graph, I have not set a base uri.

Comment: Try your current working directory as a base URI.